# Replacing 4 x 18650 batteries with 12 x AA batteries

Tags: batteries

I got an ILIFE V7S Robot vacuum that uses 4 x 18650 battery. 
It is difficult to find a replacement even from the factory in China.

So I plan to replace this with 12 x AA battery. I plan to use Panasonic BK-3MCA24/CA eneloop AA 2100 Cycle Ni-MH Pre-Charged Rechargeable ([https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07CWK26LG/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07CWK26LG)).

Based on the spec of Eneloop, each battery has 1.2V. So 12 AA would be 14.8 and that meets the required voltage of OEM battery pack.

Do you think I can use this ENELOOP AA or C-type batteries to replace the OEM ILFE battery pack?
Would it ENELOOP provide the same working hour?

The OEM can run for 3.5 hours non stop.

Thanks

The OEM battery pack spec is shown in the image [image: ILIFE V7S battery pack]

Comment: 18650 is *the* standard lithium battery cell. If it's hard to find a replacement, you've not been looking very hard.

Comment: Replacing LiIon with NiMH sounds like a terrible idea.

Comment: Marcus Müller: The OEM has a special circuit on it and it is not easy to remove it so I just cannot buy 18650 on the Amazon to replace this package. Thanks

Comment: if that circuit is necessary to operate the battery package, you won't be able to replace it with a completely different battery technology either, so that argument makes no sense.

Comment: anyway, seriously, replacing LiIon with NiMH won't work – the manufacturer wouldn't be using LiIon if that was a viable alternative.

Comment: Marcus Müller: if it works with AA batteries then it is much better for me since I bought many AA batteries for the Brava 380t and I do not have to spend additional money for a different type of battery and charger.

Comment: but NiMH are simply not suited for this device. It was designed for LiIon batteries, *because that makes sense, and because NiMH are far inferior in all aspects relevant to this application*. So you can't use them. End of story, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Would it ENELOOP provide the same working hour?*

The Amazon AA batteries are rated at 2000 mAh typical (if you believe Amazon and that's a "big if"). The Lithium in the picture is 38.5 Wh (watt hours) so, if you divide that by voltage (14.8 volts) you get an ampere hour rating of 2600 mAh and that's considerably more than you get from the AAs.

There are a few other things that also might upset things like the effective series impedance (ESR) of the 12 series AA batteries - it might mean that your circuit cannot function if it takes quite high and short pulses of current.

> *The OEM has a special circuit on it and it is not easy to remove it*

This makes it less certain that any other battery other than the original will be compatible. It might be a conventional BMS circuit but it might be something that provides other functionality.